# Query for finding Sum of credit and debit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a SQL query to retrieve SUM in  DATE ranges.

this is my sudo code:

```
 SELECT da.Debit,da.Credit,
    (SELECT SUM(daa.Debit) FROM Acc.DocumentAccount daa
    INNER JOIN Acc.Document dd ON dd.Id = daa.DocumentId
     WHERE dd.Date BETWEEN '2018-03-21' AND '2018-06-21' AND daa.Id=da.id) SumDebit
     FROM Acc.DocumentAccount da 
    INNER JOIN Acc.Document d ON d.Id = da.DocumentId
    WHERE d.Date BETWEEN '2018-06-21' AND '2019-03-21'
```

consider following sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Document(
    Id INT,
    [Date] date
);


INSERT INTO Document VALUES (1,'2018-01-01');
INSERT INTO Document VALUES (2,'2018-01-02');
INSERT INTO Document VALUES (3,'2018-07-01');
INSERT INTO Document VALUES (4,'2018-07-02');
CREATE TABLE DocumentAccount(
    DocumentId INT,
    Debit INT,
    Credit INT
    );

INSERT INTO DocumentAccount VALUES (1,100,200);
INSERT INTO DocumentAccount VALUES (2,150,300);
INSERT INTO DocumentAccount VALUES (3,150,300);
INSERT INTO DocumentAccount VALUES (4,160,310);
INSERT INTO DocumentAccount VALUES (4,170,320);

CREATE TABLE DocumentAccountDetail
(
    DocumentAccountId INT,
    DetailId INT 
)
```

I need this hard coded data:

```
select * from 
(values (250, 500,0,0,480,0,0,0,930,0)) x(RemainDebit, RemainCredit,Q1Debit,Q2Debit,Q3Debit,Q4Debit,Q1Credit,Q2Credit,Q3Credit,Q4Credit)
```

`RemainDebit` is sum of `debit` between '2018-03-21' AND '2018-06-21'

`RemainCredit` is sum of `credit` between `'2018-03-21'` AND `'2018-06-21'`

`Q1Debit` is sum of `debit` between `'2018-01-01'` AND `'2018-03-30'` in this case because my filter range is BETWEEN `'2018-06-21'` AND `'2019-03-21'` Q1Debit is 0

`Q2Debit` is sum of `debit` between `'2018-04-01'` AND `'2018-06-30'` in this case because my filter range is BETWEEN `'2018-06-21'` AND `'2019-03-21'` Q1Debit is 0

`Q3Debit` is sum of `debit` between `'2018-06-01'` AND `'2018-09-30'` in this case because my filter range is BETWEEN `'2018-06-21'` AND `'2019-03-21'` and we have 3 document in 2018-07 then  Q1Debit is 150+160+170=480

etc...

Comment: Instead of giving sudo code, you should provide sample data and expected output

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added some more detail..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question you don't need a subquery on `select` clause, you can use `JOIN` in two tables and set date range on `where` clause

```
Select 
   Sum(debit) as Totledebit,
   Sum(credit) as Totlecredit
From DocumentAccount da 
INNER JOIN Document d on da.DocumentId = d.id
WHERE d.[Date] BETWEEN '2018-03-21' AND '2019-03-21'
```

[SQLFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=89252d32232835ee09bf18ae4fa4df97)

**EDIT**

I saw you edit your question, thought there is some logic is strange.
But I believe, you can try to use `CASW WHEN` expression and `Sum` function to make your expect.

```
Select 
   Sum(CASE WHEN d.[Date]  between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-06-21'  THEN debit ELSE 0 END) as Totledebit,
   Sum(CASE WHEN d.[Date]  BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-06-21'  THEN credit ELSE 0 END) as Totlecredit,
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.[Date]  between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-03-30'  AND  d.[Date]  BETWEEN '2018-06-21' AND '2019-03-21' THEN debit ELSE 0 END) as Q1Debit,
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.[Date]  between '2018-04-01' AND '2018-06-30'  AND  d.[Date]  BETWEEN '2018-06-21' AND '2019-03-21'  THEN debit ELSE 0 END) as Q2Debit,
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.[Date]  between '2018-07-01' AND '2018-09-30'  AND  d.[Date]  BETWEEN '2018-06-21' AND '2019-03-21'  THEN debit ELSE 0 END) as Q3Debit,
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.[Date]  between '2018-10-01' AND '2018-12-31'  AND  d.[Date]  BETWEEN '2018-06-21' AND '2019-03-21'  THEN debit ELSE 0 END) as Q4Debit,
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.[Date]  between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-03-30'  AND  d.[Date]  BETWEEN '2018-06-21' AND '2019-03-21'  THEN Credit ELSE 0 END) as Q1Credit,
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.[Date]  between '2018-04-01' AND '2018-06-30'  AND  d.[Date]  BETWEEN '2018-06-21' AND '2019-03-21'  THEN Credit ELSE 0 END) as Q2Credit,
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.[Date]  between '2018-07-01' AND '2018-09-30'  AND  d.[Date]  BETWEEN '2018-06-21' AND '2019-03-21'  THEN Credit ELSE 0 END) as Q3Credit,
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.[Date]  between '2018-10-01' AND '2018-12-31'  AND  d.[Date]  BETWEEN '2018-06-21' AND '2019-03-21'  THEN Credit ELSE 0 END) as Q4Credit
From DocumentAccount da 
INNER JOIN Document d on da.DocumentId = d.id
```

sqlfiddle:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=de775aaf8c5e03b25c346dca3bd80e21

[CASE WHEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: By far the simplest solution that is aligned with the code in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I need RemainDebit and RemainCredit before this date '2018-03-21' AND '2019-03-21', in this case RemainDebit is 100+150=250 and RemainCredit is 200+300=500

Comment: @ElhamAzadfar It will didn't match any data when then date range is `between '2018-03-21' AND '2018-06-21'`

Comment: @ElhamAzadfar I edit my answer and add some information you can add your logic on `CASW WHEN` expression

Answer (score 1):

Seems here that you need a pivot, here is an idea how to compute this:

for each data range you assign a number, so

- date between '2018-03-21' AND '2018-06-21' should be tagged as 1
- date between '2018-06-21' AND '2019-03-21' should be tagged as 2
- and so on...

To achieve this you just have to create a calculated column on your table.

Then you just have to use the group by on the new column and make the SUM.

Here is a code sample:

```
WITH temp_tbl (Debit, Credit, date_grp) AS (
SELECT da.Debit AS Debit,da.Credit AS Credit
    CASE d.Date 
    WHEN BETWEEN '2018-03-21' AND '2018-06-21' THEN 1
    WHEN BETWEEN '2018-06-21' AND '2019-03-21' THEN 2
    ELSE 0
    END AS date_grp
FROM Acc.DocumentAccount da 
INNER JOIN Acc.Document d ON d.Id = da.DocumentId)

SELECT SUM(Debit), SUM(Credit), date_grp
FROM temp_tbl
GROUP BY date_grp
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This might point you in the right direction...

```
Select 
   Sum(debit) as Dr,
   Sum (credit) as cr,
   Eomonth(datecolumn) as monthend
From table
    Group by eomonth (datecolumn)
```

If you only want one row outputted with Dr and cr amounts remove line 4 in the code and filter the date.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by making SQL Functions, although the other answer is also very much considerable.

Function that will give result for Credit sum:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CreditSum (@Dt1 Date ,@Dt2 Date)
AS
BEGIN 

DECLARE @Sum decimal(10,2)

SELECT @sum = SUM(Credit) FROM Acc.DocumentAccount da 
INNER JOIN Acc.Document d ON d.Id = da.DocumentId WHERE DT BETWEEN @Dt1 And @Dt2

RETURNS @Sum
END
```

Function that will give result for debit sum:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DebitSum (@Dt1 Date ,@Dt2 Date)
AS
BEGIN 

DECLARE @Sum decimal(10,2)

SELECT @sum = SUM(Debit) FROM Acc.DocumentAccount da 
INNER JOIN Acc.Document d ON d.Id = da.DocumentId WHERE DT BETWEEN @Dt1 And @Dt2

RETURNS @Sum
END
```

Now You can get result anytime by just

```
SELECT DBO.CreditSum('2018-03-21','2018-06-21'),DBO.DebitSum('2018-03-21','2018-06-21'),DBO.CreditSum('2018-06-21',CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)),DBO.DebitSum('2018-06-21',CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the following

```
SELECT da.Debit,da.Credit,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(daa.Debit),0) FROM Acc.DocumentAccount daa
INNER JOIN Acc.Document dd ON dd.Id = daa.DocumentId
 WHERE dd.Date BETWEEN '2018-03-21' AND '2018-06-21' AND da.AccountId=daa.AccountId) SumDebit
 FROM Acc.DocumentAccount da 
INNER JOIN Acc.Document d ON d.Id = da.DocumentId
WHERE d.Date BETWEEN '2018-06-21' AND '2019-03-21'
```